# How to erase the empty space at the end of a WordSpace page

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm building a page with [Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/) and using differents plugins to support its functionalities.

When I putted [Ninja Form](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ninja-forms/) in a new page, then I got a huge white space at the end of my page. I got same resaukt with another form plugins in new pages so it looks like a common behavior of Wordpress with plugins.

This is my link ... http://gonzalo-re.com.ar/prensa/

Could you help me? Regards

Comment: Show some code , inspect elemet then show your html and css

Comment: Hi @M0ns1f... Houtan has found the answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason
replace this in your index

```
div, span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

with this:

```
div, span {
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 100%;  should be removed */
}
```

this photo could help:

[image: see this image]

this is line number of style on your index.php

[image: index.php]

Comment: It looks like "the answer"... now I have to find where is the css code to change (it's not on index.php). Thank You so much...

Comment: this is here 'http://gonzalo-re.com.ar/prensa/index,php'. you have to see style on this line number: 1391